# How do you access your "special vehicles" in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When I buy special vehicles (military vehicles) I get the message that they have been delivered, but they are not in my garage or my hanger. I bought the military humvee (don't know the name) but when I press right on the D-pad nothing pops when I'm in the garage. I bought the tank, but it did not show up in my hanger. But when I bought the attack helicopter it showed up on my helipad. Anyone understand this madness?

Comment: Odd, when I bought the tank, it did appear in my hangar (where planes appear). After your purchase you'll get a mail that says they got your order. You can only access your new vehicle after you received that mail, did you get said mail?

Comment: Yes, I have gotten a confirmation e-mail for each one.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the hangar and it will ask if you want to change stored vehicles